# Equation of every plane going through the intersection of two planes

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I'm looking for a proof of the following theorem:

If P1 written as $A = px + qy + rz +d = 0$ and P2 written as  $B = p'x + q'y + r'z + d' = 0$

All the planes going through the line intersection of P1 and P2 can be written as:
$$A+mB = 0 \ \text{ or }\  B + mA = 0.$$
 It means that the plane A + mB = 0 and P1 and P2 have the same line intersection.

Example: Find the plane going through $(1,4,2)$ And the intersection of

$P1: 2x+3y-z=6$

$P2: 3x-2y+z=0$

$2x+3y-z-6+m(3x-2y+z)=0 $ placing the point in this equation we get $m=2$
So the plane is $2x+3y-z-6+2(3x-2y+z)=0 $ 
Or $8x-y+z=6$

Comment: proposition is not true, no value of m gives the solution plane B

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that doesn't matter which plane A or B has the coefficient m

Answer (score 1):

As f5r5e5d says, you can't get plane $P_2$ this way. Clearly each equation
$A+mB=0$ is satisfied by all points on $L=P_1\cap P_2$. Let $P_3$ be a plane, different from $P_1$ and $P_2$ through line $L$. Let $Q$ be a point
on $P_3$ but not on $L$. Then $Q$ is neither on $P_1$ nor on $P_2$.
So $A(Q)\ne0$ and $B(Q)\ne0$. (Here $A(Q)$ is what you get when you put in the coordinates of $Q$ into $A=px+qy+rz+d$ etc.) Take $m=-A(Q)/B(Q)$.
Then $Q$ lies on $A+mB=0$ so that's an equation for $P_3$.

Comment: See my edit and response to @f5r5e5d

Comment: The clearly part is my question. I don't understand why this new equation goes through L

Comment: If $R$ is a point on $L$ then $(A+mB)(R)=A(R)+mB(R)=0+m\times 0=0$.

Comment: Right thanks. Don't you think that solving this kind of question this way is much simpler and faster than the procedure of many books like Thomas calculus which finds n1Xn2 them finds a point.